# How to store value of variable if it is changed inside of ajax callback function?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a form with several ajax callback functions.
And I have a variable which should change its value inside these  callback functions.
Unfortunately, I have faced with a problem. Namely, I don't know how to store the value of the variable after change. Because after the callback function executed the value is lost.

There is a little example of code.

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {
    public $i = 0;

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    ...
    $form['add_more'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Add More ...',
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::addMore',
        ]
    ];
    ...
}

public function addMore(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    ...
    $this->i++;
    ...
}
}
```

Here the variable $i doesn't increase its value whenever the button is being pressed.
Could you clarify, what should I do if I want the variable to increase its value whenever the button has been pressed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax callback is not for form logic. It's only supposed to send back a new version of `$form` or part of it in a wrapper. Or in more advanced cases a collection of ajax commands.

Use instead `buildForm()`. You can check which button was clicked with `$form_state->getTriggeringElement()`.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="ajax_wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $i = $form_state->get('elem') ? $form_state->get('elem') : 1;
    $trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    if (isset($trigger['#ajax']['callback']) && $trigger['#ajax']['callback'] === '::addMore') {
      $i++;
    }
    $form_state->set('elem', $i);

    $form['counter'] = [
      '#markup' => $form_state->get('elem') ?? 1,
    ];

    $form['btn'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => 'Btn',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::addMore',
        'wrapper' => 'ajax_wrapper',
      ]
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function addMore(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

  }
```

Comment: I created a test form, but it doestn't work.
Here is the code - https://slexy.org/view/s2NVttIMjM
A field "counter" should display changing value of the iterator, but it doesn't do it.

Comment: You need to add a wrapper and some minor things (type button for ajax, get() instead of getValue()), then it works. I've modified your latest code example.

Comment: Your code didn't work, but I added into method submitForm the following content "$form_state->setRebuild();" and it has worked.

Comment: You don't need this for the example to work, but this is a good idea as fallback, if js is not available.

Comment: But if I doesn't return $form, but execute several Ajax operations in the callback function ? 
That is, I create an AjaxResponce object, next I add several different ajax commands into it, and I returns the object instead $form.

Could you clarify me, what should i do in this case ?

Comment: A form rebuild without js always returns the complete form, so this is difficult to replicate then (but this would be a different topic I think, the example works fine with js enabled and without rebuild)

Comment: In my task I have to return the AjaxResponse object instead a $form. Can I store the value of the variable in this case ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it as in the example. We got off topic with your remark that you need to set rebuild, which is not necessary for the example to work, but might be for other things.